How to uninstall any pre-installed/system app from Ubuntu?
I am new to linux/ubuntu and I intend to use it forever, so I am learning it bit by bit as I come accross a problem or a task. Your help will always be much appreciated, Thanks .
I want to completely remove/uninstall some pre-installed apps from Ubuntu 22.04 that I don't need, to keep my system clean and customized, such as: libreoffice, thunderbird, rhythmbox, videos, and many more.
What are the steps to select and remove a specific system/preinstalled app from Ubuntu?
Thank you .

What benefit do you expect from removing packages, as opposed to leaving them installed and unused. Can you predict your requirements a decade in advance?

I guess not, well, can I hide those unused apps in app grid to keep my grid clean? thank you for your time. much appreciated.

Apps are provided in package format; so removal will be of the package they came within) as that matters. If they are a deb package you can apt remove (or apt purge to also remove..) however if snap package it'll be snap remove .....   There can be consequences also in the future (ie. apps may re-install if removed.. OR if you ensure they don't re-install you may have problems when it comes time to release-upgrade to a newer release.. so considerations also vary per package too.

Does this answer your question? How to uninstall LibreOffice?

If you do this, always look over the list of what is going to be uninstalled, don't blindly accept it. Consider starting over with the minimum install.

You can use Synaptic, which is a graphical installer/uninstaller. Installed software is highlighted by colors and the packages have a description which tells what the purpose of the package is.
You can also get information about dependencies which can help to remove packages which look superfluous but are needed by some other things which you wish to keep.
For snap packages, you can list them by
snap list 

and completly deinstall with
snap remove --purge chromium

for example. This is terribly slow, I just found out. :)
snap info cups | sed '/^commands:/q' 

Snap info gives you information about a package, here cups.
If you prefer the command line for deb-Packages, use
sudo apt purge thunderbird 

for example. The purge will remove configuration files as well, while remove will keep those.

synaptic only works on deb packages, thus pre-installed and unwanted snap packages will not be seen by synaptic and thus cannot be removed with it. Most default Ubuntu ISOs now include snap packages by default, though even with noble or what will be 24.04 there are some installs that don't include snap & snapd infrastructure; those are the minority of systems.

Well, I'm still on 22.04, where only a fraction came as snap. And since my memory told me, that it can be installed with apt/synaptic, I thought you could remove it that way, too, but not while answering, where I didn't think about snaps. I meanwhile added snaps to my answer.
